# QGIS duplicating feature not creating geometry

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geometry

I created as a .csv file a list of dates and addresses which I georeferenced through Google map to create a shapefile layer where points were categorized by attributes.  I realized later that I had forgotten to add one frequently occurring point. After manually adding this new point and filling in the attribute form, it saved properly. However, when I tried to duplicate it using the “Duplicate Feature,” it created a new feature where I could modify a value for date. However, when I created a heat map for the features, they showed up in the feature count but not on the heat map. When I tried to flash the new feature, I got nothing. And when I tried to pan to it, I received the error message: `“Pan to feature id failed: Feature does not have a geometry."` I noticed a “Duplicated Feature and Digitize” which is not explained in reference. It requires that I click on the point to create a geometry. Is there a way to duplicate and create a geometry just by duplicating a feature?

As a workaround, I just created new points on top of the old point feature, but that required reentering all the attribute information because it defaults into “Form view” rather than “Table view.” And I am unable to find any way to duplicate rows or columns as one would do with Excel. What am I missing, to duplicat attributes with geometry and can it be done without the cumbersome process of refilling forms?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select feature
2. Menu Edit > Copy Features
3. Menu Edit > Paste Features
4. Make the necessary changes in the attributes of the new feature

Comment: That does not work. TO copy a feature in an attribute table, one needs a georeferenced point to then paste it in. It will not create a new duplicate feature merely by pasting.  What perplexes me is that for 100's of features in some earlier versions of Qgis, it worked effortlessly. (I am using 3.28.1).

Comment: So then I don't seem to understand the question... The feature you have consists of attributes only, but does not have a geometry? You wanto to do... what exactly`?

Comment: I want to create a new feature with the same geometry but different attributes--such as a different date for a visit to the same location for purpose of generating a heat map.

Comment: In your question, you write you want to "duplicate attributes with geometry", now in your comment you write about "create a new feature with (...) different attributes"... it's quite confusing. I would advice to re-write the question carefully in simple words and to add a screenshot that shows what you want to do... Sharing sample data could also help understanding the problem.